# A generalization of additive function over $\mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, special-functions

> Let $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be a continuous function and $r\ge0$ a fixed value such that for all $x,y\in\mathbb R$
>   $$|f(x)+f(y)-f(x+y)|\le r$$
>   Show there exist $a\in\mathbb R$ and a function $g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ such that for all $x\in\mathbb R$$$|g(x)|\le r,\quad f(x)=g(x)+ax$$

As we might see, if $r=0$, then $f(x)+f(y)=f(x+y)$ and the answer for such a function is $f(x)=cx$ so $$g=0,\quad a=c$$
Satisfy the condition.

But I have difficulties to show this generalization, here's the things I did:

If $|f(x)-ax|\le r$, then:
$$-r\le f(x)-ax\le r\,\equiv\, \frac{-r+f(x)}{|x|}\le a\le \frac{r+f(x)}{|x|}$$
So for every $x\neq0$, we have an interval for desired $a$ (also for $x=0$, we can use the inequality and see $f(0)\le r$ so $|f(0)-a\cdot0|\le r$ holds for all $a\in \mathbb R$)

We define sets $$A_x=\{\,a\,|\,a\in[\dfrac{-r+f(x)}{|x|},\dfrac{r+f(x)}{|x|}]\,\}$$ and $A_0=\mathbb R$, I think if we show for all $x,y\in\mathbb R$
$$A_x\cap A_y\neq\emptyset$$
Then problem would be solved, but I was unable to show that.

Comment: At least you know that $g(x) = f(x)-x f(1)$.

Comment: @Dark how did you reach that conclusion?

Comment: Just an intuition actually. Don't you think it would be a reasonable guess ?

Comment: @Dark hmm, now I see. There's just a good feeling about it.

Comment: Actually the solution is $g(x) = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(2^n x)}{2^n}$

Comment: @Dark Alright, I can see $|f(x)-\dfrac{f(x2^n)}{2^n}|\le r$, so I think you mean $$g(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x)-\dfrac{f(x2^n)}{2^n}$$ And you have any idea how to show $f-g$ is linear? or even why does that limit exist.

Comment: The whole solution is there http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1078310/pdf/pnas01627-0030.pdf (spoiler alert)

Comment: @Dark Thank you so much, sir. It completely clarified me!